# php array offset 0, when 0 exists

Tags: php, arrays

when i echo

```
print_r(array_values(array_filter($exampleArray[5]["Numbers"])));
```

I get an array which looks like

```
Array ( [0] => 100 
        [1] => 31 
        [2] => 023 )
```

But when i echo the statement

```
print_r(array_values(array_filter($exampleArray[5]["Numbers"][0])));
```

I get

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

messages.
Clearly there is a 0 index but i don't know why i'm getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple As that `$exampleArray[5]["Numbers"][0]` is not an array rather it is a String.

If you want to get the index`[0]` value you should call index `0` on `array_values` response

```
print_r(array_values(array_filter($exampleArray[5]["Numbers"]))[0]);
```

The above code will return `100`